# How to duplicate magento test server

Tags: magento, digital-ocean

How do I duplicate my production site to a preprod domain?

I have a live site @ www.theprinterdepo.com

I have a sub domain preprod.theprinterdepot.net

I copied the folders over to the folder for the preproduction site, but its an exact copy of the original, so it always redirects to www.theprinterdepo.com. Anybody have experience with this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Several steps involved in cloning or moving a website.](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35119/553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also duplicate the database, and update your app/etc/local.xml with the duplicated database details so that your pre-production site is referencing it.

Then you need to specify the new BASE URL in the Magento configuration, or else it will redirect to the production site.

```
preprod.theprinterdepot.net
```

If the (preprod.theprinterdepot.net) domain is not publically accessible, then specify it in your local hosts file for example:

```
192.168.2.1    preprod.theprinterdepot.net
```

You can find an overview of the complete move details @ [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server)